# Python Websocket Flutter Client

Tags: python, flutter, websocket

i have a little problem, i am tried to program a Websocket Server in Python and a Flutter App which serve as client, but it dosent works. It establish a connection but than is over no more interaction possible.

here my python Code:

```
import socket
from SqlServerRequest import SqlServerRequest


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    # now our endpoint knows about the OTHER endpoint.
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Hey there!!!","utf-8"))
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    if data == "exit":
        break
    if data == "data":
        d = SqlServerRequest.readData()
        clientsocket.send(bytes(d,"utf-8"))
```

and i toke the flutter example from flutter docs:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
        channel: IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.16.126:1234'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.channel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: widget.channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
                  child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data.toString()}'  : ""),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',

        child: Icon(Icons.send),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      widget.channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

[Scrennshot from Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyVRC.png)

Update:
Now i am understand, that the data from Client is for handshake but i can not find any tutorial or somethink else where explain how to return the data to client to finish the authentification

Comment: I would suggest to try removing the `clientsocket.send(bytes("Hey there!!!","utf-8"))` line in Python, since the Dart/Flutter program just seems to send data without receiving any.

Comment: i already tried, that was not the problem. In the meantime i have removed it. It have to be something with the authentification

Comment: i solved it, i just replace socket.gethostname(), 1234 with my local ip adress, in my case 192.168.16.126:1234 -> it works